# Locating `subl` in OS X

Tags: sublimetext2

I have the `subl` command line tool installed in my machine (OS X 10.9.2). It works fine. But I need to know where it is. So I type:

```
which subl
```

in a Terminal window. But the behavior is as if the command did not exist.

[image]

As you can imagine, Googling "which command yields no output" is not very helpful.

Comment: Is it possible it's an alias of some sort?

Comment: Yes. I don't know how I missed that. So, `which` will not output anything when you use an alias as an argument?

Comment: Exactly, an alias is a shell thing not a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find if something is an alias, a shell builtin, or an executable program, use `type`:

```sh
# on my system
$ type dir
dir is aliased to `ls -FaGl`
$ type pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
$ type du
du is /usr/bin/du
```

It's ***much*** faster than using an unindexed `locate` command.

Answer (score 0):

Use `locate` to find all filenames with `subl`

`locate subl`

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid that. But I just started generating the database. Will report back once it's done.

Comment: It turns out that @DanZimm was right. It was an alias. I had expected `which` to output something when given an alias as an argument, but I guess I was wrong.